# bash: display value from file

Tags: bash

I have very simple client-server program in bash, server is running in infinite loop and just waiting for client activity, client role is to take a digit from user and write it to `data.txt` file then server reads the number and calculate very simple math function and then writes the result to `result.txt`.

Eventually client reads the result from `result.txt` and should display it to screen but it doesn't for some reason, I suspect the problem is with "if statement" on client site, without this statement program works but display previous calculated result. Will appreciate any suggestions.

server code:

```
#!/bin/bash
while [ 1 ]
do
  data="$(cat data.txt)"
  if [ -s data.txt ];
  then
    x=1
    for ((i=2 ; i<="$data" ; i++))
    do
      let x=x*i;
    done
    echo "$x" > result.txt
  fi
  : > data.txt
done
```

client code:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ -s result.txt ];
then
  : > result.txt
fi
echo "Enter digit"
read digit
echo "$digit" > data.txt
echo "$(cat result.txt)"
```

Comment: Try shellcheck.net.

Comment: Done already, no bugs has been found.